# How to define an acronym? using capital or small letters?

Tags: acronyms

Consider the following sentence:

"Those elements are called Super Elements (SE)".

It is ok to write like that ?  Or should I write:

"Those elements are called *super elements* (SE)".

or would it be better to also use italics?

"Those elements are called *Super Elements* (SE)".

or

"Those elements are called *Super Elements* (*SE*)".

...

Comment: This will depend on the Style Guide of the publication you are writing for.  If you are writing for yourself, then you can do it however you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Those elements are called Super Elements (SE)"

I would weigh in on capitalization without italicization. Since your end goal is to make it known that 'Super Element' is going to be denoted as 'SE', the capitalization should be used at the very least. Italics are most *commonly* used to make something stick out in a block of text. It is like a note to the reader that the word has added emphasis or meaning.

[Sonar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonar) and [Laser](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Light-Amplification-by-Stimulated-Emission-of-Radiation-(LASER).html) also show this type of layout in capitalization.

In addition, it may be appropriate to mention that 'SE' in your case would be an *initialism* as opposed to an *acronym*. Acronyms are pronounced as if they were words, whereas an initialism is stated one letter at a time. Just some fun knowledge to realize how the term *acronym* is widely used as a blanket statement =).

Examples: [Clicky](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/abbreviations/abbreviations-acronyms-and-initialisms-revisited/)

Comment: Thanks! Interesting to know the difference between acronym/initialism.